# Safari mobile - onbeforeonload support/workaround

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I'm looking for a reliable-ish workaround to onbeforeunload for Safari Mobile (let's say on iOS 7). My purpose is to prevent users to leave the page in any way if certain conditions are verified.

I know I'm not the first who asked this, but I'd like first of all to determine the 'state of art' about the support of events like this, as the other answers I found about this subject are 2+ years ago.

At the moment my best solution is an intricate combination of:

- onpopstate, to detect actions on browser's navigation button
- handlers on click/submit/any other possible action on page active elements

Still unable to detect and prevent:

- page reloads
- navigation to other pages e.g. via bookmarks

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: -narrows eyes at you- Why are you trying to stop navigation away from your page?

Comment: My page includes a text editor, and I want to make sure that users don't leave the page without saving. Definitely not cheating here :)

Comment: So just save drafts regularly like StackOverflow does.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't comply with the requirements...

Comment: Then your requirements are wrong.